# ASP.NET Core Web API Model binding behavior change

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have simple controller with custom model type *Heading* - **without parameterless constructor and public setter**.

I tried following code in asp.net mvc core 2.2 and 3.1.

Model class:

```
public class Heading
{
    public string Title { get; }
    public Heading(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

API Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Heading value)
    {
    }
}
```

With .net core 2.2, binding works perfectly. But for core 3.1, it throws error

> System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of reference types
>   without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type
>   'WebApplication3.Controllers.Heading'    at
>   System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_DeserializeCreateObjectDelegateIsNull(Type
>   invalidType)

Is this change in behaviour? Can it still be achieved?

Comment: I'm suprised a model without parameterless constructor was actually supported in .net core 2.2 . How did it even work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **ASP.NET Core 2.2**, it works just because of `Newtonsoft.Json`. In **ASP.NET Core Version >= 3.0** it was replaced by `System.Text.Json`. [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) is more about `System.Text.Json`, the new default ASP.NET Core JSON Serializer.

If you’d like to switch back to the previous default of using `Newtonsoft.Json`, do the following:

First Install the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/) NuGet package. Then in `ConfigureServices()` add a call to `AddNewtonsoftJson()` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...
     services.AddControllers()
          .AddNewtonsoftJson()
     ...
 }
```

For more details: [ASP.NET Core 3.0 - New JSON serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-3.1#new-json-serialization)

Answer (score 1):

Although you can change the default serializer and return to the previous functionality `Newtonsoft.Json` as mentioned by @TanvirArjel, the ideal is to use the default serializer `System.Text` as it has better performance. You can check it here: [How to migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to) The error is caused due to the fact that the Heading class does not have a constructor valid without arguments which should be defined as follows.

```
public class Heading {
    Heading(){
    }
    public string AttrOne {get; set;}
    public string AttrTwo {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#complex-types):

**Complex types**

```
A complex type must have a public default constructor and public writable properties to bind. When model binding occurs, the class is instantiated using the public default constructor.
```

You will need to add a parameter-less constructor for binding to use that model.

The behavior may have worked for you before (2.2 and prior) if you were using NewtonsoftJson which may have allowed parameter-less constructor models. Since 3.0 .NET Core [uses the newer System.Text.Json serializer by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support).

Comment: @vyas-bharghava Thanks for cleaning up the links!